# Weird problem with PHP mail() under Linux

Tags: php, email, mime

This is the case when it "works on my machine". Except that my machine is Windows, and the target is some sort of Linux.

The idea is that the `mail()` function puts a newline between the `MIME-Version` and `Content-Type` headers, thus breaking the whole thing. Here's the code, simpliefied as much as possible:

```
<?php
        $HTMLPart = chunk_split(base64_encode('<html><body style="color: red">Test.</body></html>'));
        $PlaintextPart = chunk_split(base64_encode('>>> TEST <<<'));

$Headers     =<<<AKAM
From: "My Test" <my@mail.com>
Reply-To: my@mail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="9-1410065408-1410065408=:27514"
AKAM;

$Body        =<<<AKAM
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--9-1410065408-1410065408=:27514
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="windows-1252"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

$PlaintextPart
--9-1410065408-1410065408=:27514
Content-Type: text/html; charset="windows-1252"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

$HTMLPart
--9-1410065408-1410065408=:27514--
AKAM;
    echo 'Try 3: ';
    echo mail('your@mail.com', 'Testmail', $Body, $Headers) ? 'WIN' : 'FAIL';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a carriage return AND a line feed there.  Windows uses CR+LF to end lines, but Linux uses a line feed alone.